# The method must not be replaced by the superclass

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to add Facebook Ads(sdk 6.3.0) in my Android App

The documentation on which I base myself

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reference/android/com/facebook/ads/interstitialad.html/?version=v6.3.0

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/ad-setup/android/interstitial/

I want when the person clicks on a button it shows an ad and then a new activity when the ad end
I also use a return which directly shows the activity if no ads are available

**Here are the errors I am getting**

```
The onInterstitialDisplayed method must not be replaced by the superclass
The onInterstitialDismissed method must not be replaced by the superclass
The onError method must not be replaced by the superclass
The onAdLoaded method must not be replaced by the superclass
The onAdClicked method must not be replaced by the superclass
The onAdLoaded method must not be replaced by the superclass
```

**What I have done**

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
 
        AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
        loadAd();
        clickListener();
    }
```

```
private void clickListener() {
        
        dailyCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInterstitialAd(1);
                }
        });
                rewardCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showInterstitialAd(2);
                }
        });
}
```

```
private void loadAd(){
        
        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "750944672287722_755093405206182");
        
    }
```

```
    private void showInterstitialAd(final int i) {

        if (mInterstitialAd.isAdLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new InterstitialAd.InterstitialLoadAdConfig() {
                
                    @Override
                    public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                        
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            dailyCheck();
                        }
                        
                        if (i == 2)
                        {
                            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RewardActivity.class));
                        }
                        
                    }   
                
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                        
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                        
                    }       
            });
            return;
        }
        
        if (i == 1)
        {
            dailyCheck();
        }
        
        if (i == 2)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RewardActivity.class));
        }
        
    }
```

Any help is good to take!

Thank you

Comment: Call the parent's method. `super.onInterstitialDisplayed(ad)`.

Comment: @Darkman you'd think the error should then read: "The xxx method must not be replaced by the _sub_ class", no?

Comment: Do you have an idea of ​​the problem ?

Comment: The `InterstitialAd.InterstitialLoadAdConfig` is a marker interface (it has no methods) so I suspect the `Override` tags are problematic - what do you think you are overriding?